# TSQL How do I update a Temp Table column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, temp-tables

I have a temp table that needs to pull from different databases. The reason is that each DB holds information in a separate group of employees, and we are trying to create a report that pulls them all into one file. To do that, when I create the temp table I say:

```
Select ...
       ,...
       ,CAST(NULL AS int) AS 'FedExemptions'
       ,...
INTO #TaxInfo
FROM #....
```

And then I update the FedExemptions column like so:

```
UPDATE #TaxInfo
set FedExemptions = (SELECT ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
                 FROM <db1>.EMPS
                 WHERE CONVERT(int, <db1>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo)
UPDATE #TaxInfo
set FedExemptions = (SELECT ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
                 FROM <db2>.EMPS
                 WHERE CONVERT(int, <db2>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo)
UPDATE #TaxInfo
set FedExemptions = (SELECT ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
                 FROM <db3>.EMPS
                 WHERE CONVERT(int, <db3>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo)
UPDATE #TaxInfo
set FedExemptions = (SELECT ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
                 FROM <db4>.EMPS
                 WHERE CONVERT(int, <db4>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo)
```

However, The last update (db4) will overwrite the other previous 3 updates, setting the Fedexemptions of the previous three groups to 0

I do not understand why. I could swear the:

```
WHERE CONVERT(int, <db4>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo
```

would make it so SSMS wouldn't touch the rows when the emp numbers didn't match.

As a side note, I am doing the CONVERT on the Emp number because one the #TaxInfo Emp numbers are INTs, and the <db> Databases are varchars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me reformat that query:

```
UPDATE #TaxInfo
SET FedExemptions = (
    SELECT ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
    FROM <db4>.EMPS
    WHERE CONVERT(int, <db4>.EMPS.EMP) = #TaxInfo.EmpNo
)
```

So now you can see there is no `WHERE` clause on the *outer* query. For every single row, the value will be set to what is returned from the inner query.

I think you want to do something more like this:

```
UPDATE t SET FedExemptions = ISNULL(e.FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0)
FROM #TaxInfo t
JOIN <db4>.EMPS e ON CONVERT(int, e.EMPS.EMP) = t.EmpNo
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Seems I need a rubber ducky around because that that looks straight forward enough, my mind just refused to think of that...

Answer (score 2):

Ok so many things going on here that don't make sense.

First, correlated sub-queries are a terrible way to do an update. Use a join instead if you still do an update which actually doesn't make sense to me in any event.

Next it appears to me from your code that you want to update any records where the value is null to a 0 and grab the values in the EMPS table, so why not get them originally in the insert to the temp table? something like:

```
INsert into   #TaxInfo ( put fields here) 
Select ...
           ,...
           ,ISNULL(FEDERAL_EXEMPTIONS, 0) AS 'FedExemptions'
           ,...

    FROM #....
```

You might need to add a join to the EMPS table depending on your actual initial query. It is also a best practice to specifically define the columns in your temp table and in your insert. What happens if someone changes the structure of your databases?

Also since you are getting empnos from multiple tables in different databases are you sure they are not repeated? Could empno 200 be one person in database A and someone else in database b? You really need to check for this sort of thing.

You also might consider if it would be worth it to create a view that is a  union of all of these tables and then query the view. This is the best thing if there will be other queries that also need to hit all these tables. And if you have occasion to add another database with yet another EMPS table that need to get added to all those queries, it is simpler to drop and recreate the view than look for 1000 different queries that reference those tables.